# Sliding Up Panel Layout - Increase smoothly Panel Height

Tags: android, height

I'm working with SlidingUpPanelLayout and I need to use diferent drag views with different height. So I have to set the Panel height programmatically for the diferents drag vies. Now, I need that the change of the panel height to be smoothly. For example, this is the code to inflate the new drag view, with is own height, set the panel height and set the height of the container of the map:

```
/**
 * 
 */
public void loadZonesDragView(){
    dragView = activity.getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.fragment_dragview_zones, rlDragviewCont, false);   
    int panelHeightPx = dpToPx(180);

    if(dragView != null){
        // Add Drag View with properly height
        rlDragviewCont.removeAllViews();
        rlDragviewCont.addView(dragView);
        SlidingUpPanelLayout.LayoutParams paramsDragView = new SlidingUpPanelLayout.LayoutParams(
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
        rlDragviewCont.setLayoutParams(paramsDragView);

        // Map height
        DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
        activity.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams paramsMap = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                SlidingUpPanelLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                (metrics.heightPixels - panelHeightPx));
        fMap.setLayoutParams(paramsMap);

        rlDragviewCont.getLayoutTransition().setDuration(200);
        slidingLayout.setPanelHeight(panelHeightPx);
    }
}
```

I'm using this code to inflate the new drag view, set the panel height to the portion of the layout that works as the panel, and apply a duration to the layout transition of the container that contains the drag view. The drag view appears slowly (200 ms), but the panel height is set automatically. Is there any way to set the panel height at the same ritm?

Than you for your time.